Range, Endurance and Fuel Cost Savings of an Aircraft
I have recently carried out CFD simulations on the A320 fuselage and modified its fuselage.  I did this by matching the Reynold's number of the cruising altitude. The reference values were taken at the sea level conditions, v = 90.10m/s, density 1.225kg/m3 etc. I found out that the Cl and Cd values were -0.00136 and Cd value is 0.0340 with a cross sectional front profile area of 12.83m2. For the modified fuselage, the cross sectional area is 13.53m2, Cd is0.0314 and Cl is -0.0091.
I would like to calculate the Range, Endurance and Fuel cost savings due to the modified design.  How can I do this?

With only one point and only the isolated fuselage is a bit difficult to make a comparison... You need at least 3 point and the whole airplane to built the polar and then you can compare it with the official one

At a minimum, you need to vary alpha to match lift at the same flight condition and then compare the drag coefficients.
Comparing drag at different lift is meaningless.
Both analyses should be performed at a cruise condition -- not sea level, and such that Lift = Weight.  Your negative CL makes this very unlikely.
